# Is 'the hills near the wolves' an idiom in English?

Tags: idioms

In John Berger's 1984 collection of essays and poetry, *And Our Faces, My Heart, Brief As Photos*, we read:

> The transition from a nomadic life to a settled one is said to mark the beginning of what was later called civilization. Soon all those who survived outside the city began to be considered uncivilized. But that is another story – to be told in **the hills near the wolves**.

What does *the hills near the wolves* mean here?

Comment: For answerers' reference, this appears to be from John Berger's _And Our Faces, My Heart, Brief As Photos_, copyright 1984, a collection of essays and poetry.

Comment: No, it is not an idiom. Probably it is tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: It means exactly what it says: a story to be told out in the hills, near where the wolves are. Why exactly that story should be told out in the hills is not really clear, but it’s probably related to the previous sentence that mentions those living outside cities being considered uncivilised.

Comment: It's not an idiom, it has its straightforward meaning -- the story is best told when we're all sitting among the hills where the wolves are known to lurk -- but also a subtext. There's a contrast between the idea of "the cities where the 'civilized' people live" and us all "camping around in the hills, outside the city, where the nomads, the 'uncivilized' people, and also the wolves live". It's contrastive. Maybe it paints the nomads as strong and fearless, maybe it's likening them to wolves and other scary things in the dark.

Comment: I would argue that it should be parsed "to be told [in the hills] [near the wolves]" (i.e. two separate descriptions), as opposed to "to be told in [the hills near the wolves]". Makes more sense, in my opinion.